# Random Space in HTML Gallery List, How to remove/fix?

Tags: html, css, element

Site in question: https://s123c.github.io/design.html

I'm trying to make a list of elements in a 3 x 4 Portfolio Gallery. However I have spaces (3 items in width) between the first image and the beginning of the row. I've tried to look for similar topics, but I can't find anything similar to my problems as the solutions don't match up.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flaxbox is an amazing property for laying out elements. I've taken a quick look at the website and if you just add ul {display: flex} at the end of your .css file, you should no longer see the issue.

Or remove any current layout code for #gallery and add the following.

```
.container-a4 {
  display: table;
}
.caption-style-4 {
  display: table-row;
}

.caption-style-4 li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One good solution would be to use a framework like [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/), so things like horizontal scrolling won't happen and will help you create a mobile version for the website.
I am sure a framework will help you solve this issue.

of course, this will only happen if you use foundation properly, it's easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use anything, just insert this line in your style code.
Display table, table-row and table-cell causes problem sometimes, so it is best to use the list with floating elements.

```
.row {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

ul tag is little creepy, so it is best to use the overflow attribute to make the ul list act as block element.

Because you are floating you list elements to left, the ul element do not get it's height, so you should use overflow attribute.